# How many ways are there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways are there to put 14 identical objects in 3 distinct boxes with at least 8 objects in one box?

What is the thinking procedure of the similar question type?

Comment: If you don't regard the condition with 8 objects in the beginning, the problem is similar to finding the number of integer solutions to
$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 14-8
$$

Comment: I think you have to multiply above result by 3 ? @MattiP.

Comment: @rsadhvika I agree. Multiplying by 3 takes into account the 8 objects in the beginning.

Comment: I suggest looking up "generating functions" as a way to solve these integer problems.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find a unique way to describe a possible placement of the objects, that makes counting easy. Here is a solution.

- Choose the box that has at least $8$ objects: $3$ choices.
- For each of the preceding choices, let $k$ be the number of objects in this box ($8\le k\le 14$).
- For each $k$, choose the number of objects in the leftmost remaining box ($0$ to $14-k$): $15-k$ choices.
- The last box gets the remaining.

This uniquely describes the three boxes.

How many choices now?

$$3\sum_{k=8}^{14} (15-k)$$